# how i alert the name of buttons added on document using for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

i get number of buttons, loop through append that buttons on document body.
but condition is that alert the name of button. onclick alert the name of that button, please help.

```
var i;
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Button" + i);
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    if(btn.addEventListener){
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() { alert(btn.value);});    
    } else if(btn.attachEvent){ // IE < 9 :(
        btn.attachEvent('onclick', function() { alert(btn.value);});
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no name on those buttons.

Comment: Dang, I haven't mingled with pure JS in a while, but this would be incredibly easy in jquery. You simply do `alert($(this).val());` or `alert($(this).html());`

Comment: Need to add the name property first if you want to display that in alert... if you want to display the caption/text of the button , just use "btn.innerText" or "btn.innerHTML"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your code, here is the code working, first you have to add the name property, and second in the function you have to use "this" and not "btn".

The js code and a snippet to help you.

```
    // Code goes here
    var i;

      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var btn = null;
        btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        btn.setAttribute("name", i + "_name");
        var t = document.createTextNode("Button" + i);
        btn.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
        if (btn.addEventListener) {
          btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            alert("i am button " + this.getAttribute("name"));
          });
        } else if (btn.attachEvent) { // IE < 9 :(
          btn.attachEvent('onclick', function() {
            alert("i am button " + this.getAttribute("name"));
          });
        }
      }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `btn.innerHTML` instead of `btn.value`

Answer (score 0):

Changing it to `innerText` or `innerHTML` it works !

```
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Button" + i);
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    if(btn.addEventListener){
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() { alert(btn.innerText);});    
    } else if(btn.attachEvent){ // IE < 9 :(
        btn.attachEvent('onclick', function() { alert(btn.innerText);});
    }
```

Comment: using innerHTML or innerText this alert last button value. i try setattribute and this works